# Place an 'x' on top corner of image, for deleting (React Native)

Tags: react-native

When orientation changes, then use an 'x' in the top corner of the image for deletion. 
I could just place the trash icon and the name of the place (of the img) next to the img. It would be nice to learn how to place an 'x'...
plus (maybe) the name of the place on the other top corner.
Thanks

```
...
class PlaceDetail extends Component {
    state = {

    viewMode: Dimensions.get('window').height > 500 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
    }

constructor(props) {
super(props);
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', this.updateStyles )
    }

componentWillUnmount() {
 Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this.updateStyles )
    }
updateStyles = (dims) => {
    this.setState({
    viewMode: dims.window.height > 500 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
        })
    }
render(){
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<View style={this.state.viewMode === 'landscape' ? 
      styles.viewImageLandScape : null } >
    <Image 
        source={this.props.selectedPlace.image} 
        style={
        this.state.viewMode === 'portrait' ? 
        styles.placeImagePortrait :
        styles.placeImageLanscape }/>
<Text style={styles.placeName}>{this.props.selectedPlace.name}</Text>
</View>
<View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.placeDeleteHandler}>
<View style={styles.deleteButton}>
<Icon size={30} name={Platform.OS ==='android' ? "md-trash" : "ios-trash"} color="red" />
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</View>
        );
    }

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        margin: 22
    },
    placeImagePortrait: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200
    },
    viewImageLandScape: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
           alignItems: 'center',
    },
    placeImageLanscape: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 200, 
        marginTop: 0
    },
    placeName: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 28
    },
    deleteButton: {
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```

So here is the code with the name and the delete icon under the image, but in a row:

```
 class PlaceDetail extends Component {
    state = {
        viewMode: Dimensions.get('window').height > 500 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Dimensions.addEventListener('change', this.updateStyles);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this.updateStyles);
    }

    updateStyles = (dims) => {
        this.setState({
            viewMode: dims.window.height > 500 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
        });
    };

    placeDeleteHandler = () => {
        // selectedPlace: is props we pushed from FindPlace
        this.props.onDeletePlace(this.props.selectedPlace.key);
        this.props.navigator.pop();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={this.state.viewMode === 'landscape' ? styles.viewImageLandScape : null}>
                    <Image
                        source={this.props.selectedPlace.image}
                        style={
                            this.state.viewMode === 'portrait' ? styles.placeImagePortrait : styles.placeImageLanscape
                        }
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={this.state.viewMode === 'landscape' ? styles.nameAndIcon : null}>
                    <Text style={styles.placeName}>{this.props.selectedPlace.name}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.placeDeleteHandler}>
                        <View style={styles.deleteButton}>
                            <Icon size={30} name={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-trash' : 'ios-trash'} color="red" />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    container: {
        margin: 22
    },
    nameAndIcon: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
    },
    placeImagePortrait: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200
    },
    viewImageLandScape: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    placeImageLanscape: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 200
    },
    placeName: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 28
    },
    deleteButton: {
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `ImageBackground` instead of `Image`:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('YOUR_MAIN_IMAGE')} style={{height: 100, width: 200}}>
          <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={()=> your_function()}
            >
              <Image source={require('YOUR_ICON_PATH')} style={{height: 40, width: 40,margin:15}}/> 
          </TouchableHighlight>

        </ImageBackground>
```

instead of icon image you can use `<Text> X </Text>`

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried ImageBackground... I would like to post the final code. I think I should use the "Answer your Question" option, by mentioning your contribution. Thanks again :)

Comment: thanks , also you can up vote or mark as correct my answer :)) , good luck

Comment: Yes of course! Now I can vote too. Thanks again amirhosein :)

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestion of amirhosein the code took this shape:

```
class PlaceDetail extends Component {
    state = {
        viewMode: Dimensions.get('window').height > 500 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Dimensions.addEventListener('change', this.updateStyles);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this.updateStyles);
    }

    updateStyles = (dims) => {
        this.setState({
            viewMode: dims.window.height > 500 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
        });
    };

    placeDeleteHandler = () => {
        // selectedPlace: is props we pushed from FindPlace
        this.props.onDeletePlace(this.props.selectedPlace.key);
        this.props.navigator.pop();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={this.state.viewMode === 'landscape' ? styles.viewImageLandScape : null}>
                    <ImageBackground
                        source={this.props.selectedPlace.image}
                        style={
                            this.state.viewMode === 'portrait' ? styles.placeImagePortrait : styles.placeImageLanscape
                        }
                    >
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.placeDeleteHandler}>
                            <View style={styles.nameAndIcon}>
                                <Text style={styles.placeName}>{this.props.selectedPlace.name}</Text>
                                <Icon
                                    size={30}
                                    name={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-close' : 'ios-close'}
                                    color="red"
                                />
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        margin: 22
    },
    placeImagePortrait: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200
    },
    viewImageLandScape: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    placeImageLanscape: {
        width: 500,
        height: 200
    },
    placeName: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 28,
        color: 'white'
    },
    nameAndIcon: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        margin: 2,
        padding: 2
    }
});
```

It still needs some work of course...

[image]
[image]